# Multiline edit in awk

Tags: awk, multiline

```
MV: The Garden Murder Case (1936)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above format my record separator is the line of ------

I want to drop all single line records so above the first record should drop and the 2nd should be kept.

Simple enough so I thought.

```
BEGIN {RS="^[-]+$"}
  $0 !~ /^(BT|GR|OW|RT|AD)/ {next}
  1
```

I also tried checking for a record that contains 2 end of line characters

```
BEGIN {RS="^[-]+$"}
  /$.+$/
  1 {next}
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `^` and `$` in the Record separator as they are the start and end of records based on the record separator.

Try this

```
awk -vRS="\n-+\n" -F"\n" 'NF>1' file
```

#### Output

```
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000
```

If you want to retain the field separators then you can use

```
awk -vRS="\n-+\n" -F"\n" 'NF>1{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file
```

#### Input

```
MV: The Garden Murder Case (1936)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MV: The Garden Murder Case (1936)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### output

```
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MV: The Garden of Allah (1936)
BT: USD 2,200,000
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```