# awk - Why doesn't a change to $0 force reconstruction of the output record

Tags: awk

This is a follow on to the question and data dealt with here

[Multiline edit in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860634/multiline-edit-in-awk)

Following on from that answer I came up with the following solution

```
BEGIN {RS="\n-+\n"; FS="\n";OFS="\t"}
  NF > 1 {sub(/^MV: /,""); print}
```

However this did not work as the  specified OFS did not take effect. Of course sub's default behaviour is to change $0 and it seems that doesn't trigger record reconstruction (or whatever is necessary to fire the new OFS).

It does work if I change it to specify $1 in the sub command

```
BEGIN {RS="\n-+\n"; FS="\n";OFS="\t"}
  NF > 1 {sub(/^MV: /,"",$1); print}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's like asking "why doesn't index($0,3) return a substring of $0 starting at character 3?". The answer is simply - because that's not the way the language is defined.

Assigning to a field (e.g. $1) reconstructs the record replacing FS with OFS.

Assigning to $0 re-splits the record into fields using FS.

That's all.